# Indy idftp client "Invalid argument to time encode"

Tags: delphi, indy10

Using Delphi 2010 and Indy 10.5.8.0.

Against the server Titan FTP I'm getting all the time the exception "Invalid argument to time encode" (EConvertError) when connecting.

The server log tells me:

```
FEAT<EOL>
211-Extensions Supported<EOL> COMB<EOL> MLST type*;size*;modify*;create*;perm*;<EOL>    SIZE<EOL> MDTM<EOL> XCRC<EOL> REST STREAM<EOL> AUTH SSL<EOL> AUTH TLS<EOL> CCC<EOL> PBSZ<EOL> PROT<EOL> EPRT<EOL> EPSV<EOL> DQTA<EOL>211 End<EOL>
TYPE A<EOL>
200 Type set to A.<EOL>
The user "*****" has initiated a session on "217.********:21"
SYST<EOL>
215 UNIX Type: L8<EOL>
SITE ZONE<EOL>
210 UTC-2147483647<EOL>
QUIT<EOL>
221 Session Ended. Downloaded 0KB, Uploaded 0KB. Goodbye *** from 130.******.<EOL>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had same problem while connecting to our ftp server, IT guy changed the server time zone to GMT (needs restarting server), and then changed it back to local time zone. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is sending a faulty UTC offset in response to the `SITE ZONE` command.  That is a bug in Titan.  When Indy tries to parse the value for use in later `TDateTime` operations, the parse fails.  Contact the Titan devs and let them know about the bug. In the meantime, I will look into updating `TIdFTP` to handle that error in the future.